# Delete Button in Listview from SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I was wondering if somebody could further explain how to implement a delete button inside a listview that is populated from an SQLite database. I've read the responses to the following question that is essentially what I'm asking as well, but I don't understand it:

[How can I implement a delete button in a ListView and delete from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746910/how-can-i-implement-a-delete-button-in-a-listview-and-delete-from-database)

In my custom row .xml file, I included a delete button that implements the method delete() onClick. It also includes an alert dialog, by the way. Here's the code that I have so far for my delete() method; whenever I try to use it, it never gets the right activtiy entry.

```
  public void delete(View view){

    final int position = listview.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent());
    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID));

    AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    myDialog.setTitle("Delete activity entry \"" + id + "\"?");
    myDialog.setPositiveButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            mySQLiteAdapter.delete(position);
            cursor.requery();
            }
        });

    myDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            }
        });

    myDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to implement a custom ArrayAdapter.

```
 public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourObject>
    {

        private ArrayList<YourObject> items;

        public LiftArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<YourObject> items)
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_view_xml, null);


}
        final YourObject obj = items.get(position);

        TextView lblLift = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_lift);
        ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        btnDelete .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //TODO delete 'obj' from database
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

Then, to bind a list of objects to your listview:

```
    List<YourObject> list = ...
    MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter (.., .. ,  list);
    listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Will this work if I already am using another adapter? My listview is populated from an SQLite database and I used a simple cursor adapter to do so. To further explain my page, I have an edittext where users can input information which is saved into the SQLite database and displayed in the listview, but I want to be able to delete entries for the listview.

Comment: Yes, this custom adapter would have to replace your CursorAdapter. It would require you to create a List of your objects, and pass them as a argument to the MyArrayAdapter constructor.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but is there any way to do it without creating a new adapter? I'm a beginner to Android and I'm not sure how to populate a database without a cursor adapter.